# Query canceled by user id 0

Tags: amazon-redshift

Some of our queries are getting canceled with error message `Query (<query id>) cancelled on user's request`, but no user canceled them.

Querying on table `SVL_TERMINATE`, I filtered on the `PID` of the failed query, and saw many rows with `type` column value being `CANCEL`. I also found the exact timestamp of such row that matches the timestamp of one of our failed queries.

All rows for this `PID` had `USERID` = 0. What is that user? I couldn't find anything online that references a user id 0 in Redshift. I obviously guessed that `userid` 0 is Redshift canceling my user's query, but the question is why?

We noticed that around that same time, our Redshift cluster took a snapshot.
But snapshots should not cancel running queries, right?

What other events (other than restarting/upgrading the cluster) cause Redshift to cancel all running queries? I will try to check if those events happened.

Answer (score 0):

The USERID of 0 in Amazon Redshift typically represents an internal or system process rather than a specific human user. This user ID is used by the system for various internal operations, including cancelling queries due to system-level reasons such as exceeding WLM time limits or internal processing errors

Regarding snapshots, they do not directly cause queries to be cancelled.  However, taking a snapshot might temporarily impact cluster performance, which could indirectly lead to query cancellations if the system is under heavy load.
REference - https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/redshift-query-abort

Many reasons can cause Redshift to cancel all running queries include:

- Statement Timeout: If a query exceeds the statement_timeout value, Redshift terminates it
- Workload Management (WLM) Query Monitoring Rules: If WLM query monitoring rules are set up to abort queries that exceed certain thresholds, those queries will be cancelled
- Network Issues: Disruptions in network connectivity can lead to query cancellations
- Cluster Maintenance Upgrades: During maintenance windows, Amazon Redshift might cancel queries to ensure system stability
- Internal Processing Errors: Errors internal to Redshift's processing can also result in query cancellations
- ASSERT Errors: These are errors triggered by assertions within Redshift's codebase, which can lead to query cancellation

To manage and prevent query cancellations, you can:

- Increase your timeout parameter to allow queries more time to complete.
- Update your WLM QMR rules to accommodate longer-running queries.
- Schedule long-running operations outside of maintenance windows to minimize disruptions